# AFK function stopped working when I hosted the bot in Digital Ocean

Tags: python, discord

I asked about an afk function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63683549/afk-function-in-discord-bot), and it worked well until now. Yesterday I hosted the bot in Digital Ocean, so that it could be online 24/7 (I don't know if this affects the functioning of the bot, but just in case) and since then, whenever someone uses the afk function, the bot doesn't send the "this user is afk" message and the user cannot undo the afk unless they call it again. I'm very lost because I haven't changed anything from this function but yet it stopped working. Thanks in advance.
My code:

```
afkdict = {}
@client.command(name = "afk", brief = "Away From Keyboard",
                description = "I'll give you the afk status and if someone pings you before you come back, I'll tell "
                              "them that you are not available. You can add your own afk message!")
async def afk(ctx, message = "They didn't leave a message!"):
    global afkdict

    if ctx.message.author in afkdict:
        afkdict.pop(ctx.message.author)
        await ctx.send('Welcome back! You are no longer afk.')

    else:
        afkdict[ctx.message.author] = message
        await ctx.send("You are now afk. Beware of the real world!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global afkdict
    if message.author in afkdict:
        afkdict.pop(message.author)
        await message.channel.send('Welcome back! You are no longer afk.')


    for member in message.mentions:  
        if member != message.author:  
            if member in afkdict:  
                afkmsg = afkdict[member]  
                await message.channel.send(f"Oh noes! {member} is afk. {afkmsg}")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was the @client.event wasn't working because I had another client.event. When I put both together, it works without any issue!